# Меню с горизонтальным скроллингом

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, mobile

Необходимо реализовать горизонтальную прокрутку для мобильных устройств, как в Google:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идеальный вариант на CSS.
Jquery тоже приветствуется.
Примерный код:

```css
    .mobile_menu{
        position:relative; 
        color: #545454;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 75px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        font-size: 1.3em;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .mobile_menu span{
        padding-bottom: 4.5px;
        padding-left: 3%;
    }
    .mobile_menu span a{
        color:#777;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .mobile_menu span .active{
        color:#4286f5;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #4286f5;
    }
    #menu_mobile{
        position:absolute;
        width: 500px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row mobile_menu">
    <div id="menu_mobile" class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 col-sm-11 col-xs-10">
        <span><a href="#" class="active">ВСЕ</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">НОВОСТИ</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">КАРТИНКИ</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">ВИДЕО</a></span>
        <span><a href="#">КАРТА</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Это обычный блок с горизонтальным скроллом:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 0;
}

menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}

ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</menu>
```

Comment: А как скрыть скролл, но оставить возможность прокрутки ?

Comment: На десктопе никак.

Comment: @yaslik добавьте стилизацию с помощью псевдоэлемента ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0px;
} скрола не будет, возможность листать останется, например если мышь с возможностью горизонтальной прокрутки